# String operations not working in Sinatra / ERB

Tags: ruby, string, sinatra, erb

Trying to truncate a string in Ruby/Sinatra in an .erb page.
I have been trying variants of:

```
<%= @caption_str.truncate(20) %>
<%= @caption_str[0..20] %>
```

But keep getting error messages of the kind:

```
NoMethodError at /392471267473009
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

or

```
NoMethodError at /392471267473009
undefined method `truncate' for nil:NilClass
```

All is well if I don't truncate the string, i.e.

```
<%= @caption_str %>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd like to have a look at the code about @caption_str. Maybe in your sinatra base file?

Comment: Thanks @halfelf, Jatin just got to the heart of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NoMethodError at /392471267473009
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

or

```
NoMethodError at /392471267473009
undefined method `truncate' for nil:NilClass
```

The errors are descriptive enough.

They convey that there is `no [] or truncate method defined` for **nil:NilClass**, which in this case turns out to be your  `@caption_str` object.

Check if `@caption_str` is not `nil` and then do these operations. When `@caption_str` would be **nil**, you'll get the same error.

**Since, Ruby is a dynamic programming language, we tend to forget the edge-cases when the values would be nil. Always include checks when similar situations arise.**

Comment: Thanks! Got it in one. Yeah, I forgot to do the test for nil.